# How to build a covariance matrix from eigen vectors wtih the same size

Tags: numpy, covariance, eigenvector, symmetric, covariance-matrix

I have 2 eigen vectors sets `X` and `Y` with `size=(7,7)` (so 7 eigen vectors of 7 components).

I am looking for a way to build a covariance matrix from these 2 eigen vectors sets.

In a first time, I did the function :

```
# Compute covariance between vectors of matrix
def compute_Cov(A,B):
  C = np.zeros((7,7))
  for i in range(7):
    C[0:7,i]= np.mean(A[0:7,i]*B[0:7,i]) - np.mean(A[0:7,i])*np.mean(B[0:7,i])
    #C[0:7,i] = np.cov(A[0:7,i],B[0:7,i])
  return C
```

and calling : `CovXY = compute_Cov(X,Y)`

But this way, the matrix `CovXY` **is not symetric** and **I don't know how to build a symmetric matrix** from `X` and `Y` eigen vectors sets (so X and Y are actually matrices).

Comment: How unsymetric is CovXY? It is not uncommon to do Covxy = (Covxy+Covxy.T)/2 to get rid of numerical errors. You have to judge yourself based on how unsymetric the matrix is if this is the way to go.

Comment: @Bas . Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately, I think I can't apply your formula since each column corresponds to an eigen vector. So, I have to handle with an array of eigen vectors (7 columns in my case).

Comment: Are you sure that you compute covariance matrix? It seems that you compute cross-covariance matrix, which is not symmetric https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance_matrix